# Understanding short variable declaration in loop, resulting unnecessary memory allocations, when does it make sense?

Tags: go

A lot of go resources are full of code snippets/examples with short variable declarations inside loops. A quick test reveals that go allocates new memory in every iteration when one uses short variable declaration. Example below:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
        a:=i+1 // BAD!: allocates memory in every iteration
        fmt.Printf("i-val: %d, i-addr: %p, a-val: %d, a-addr: %p\n", i, &i, a, &a)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
% go build -gcflags="-m" ./shortdecl.go
# command-line-arguments
./shortdecl.go:16:19: inlining call to fmt.Printf
./shortdecl.go:12:9: moved to heap: i
./shortdecl.go:14:9: moved to heap: a
./shortdecl.go:16:19: ... argument does not escape
./shortdecl.go:16:70: i escapes to heap
./shortdecl.go:16:77: a escapes to heap

% ./shortdecl
i-val: 0, i-addr: 0x1400000e138, a-val: 1, a-addr: 0x1400000e140
i-val: 1, i-addr: 0x1400000e138, a-val: 2, a-addr: 0x1400000e150
i-val: 2, i-addr: 0x1400000e138, a-val: 3, a-addr: 0x1400000e158
i-val: 3, i-addr: 0x1400000e138, a-val: 4, a-addr: 0x1400000e160
i-val: 4, i-addr: 0x1400000e138, a-val: 5, a-addr: 0x1400000e168
i-val: 5, i-addr: 0x1400000e138, a-val: 6, a-addr: 0x1400000e170
i-val: 6, i-addr: 0x1400000e138, a-val: 7, a-addr: 0x1400000e178
i-val: 7, i-addr: 0x1400000e138, a-val: 8, a-addr: 0x1400000e180
i-val: 8, i-addr: 0x1400000e138, a-val: 9, a-addr: 0x1400000e188
i-val: 9, i-addr: 0x1400000e138, a-val: 10, a-addr: 0x1400000e190
```

A bunch of questions related to escape analysis and short declarations:

1. Why did `i` escape? Its just occupies int's size, and it's not being allocated every iteration.
2. Why did `a` escape even if the number of iterations are small?
3. If the number of iterations is increased a lot, this simple for-with-increment loop will keep allocating new pages (troubling the OS). How well is the handling of deallocation of pages?
4. Given online resources on go liberally use short declaration inside loop, is there a time when it is required or makes sense to do so?
5. Is there something that restricts go team to not allocate new  memory for `a` on every iteration? Then it can perhaps also be on stack, given its tiny size?

The following does not cause new allocation of `a` every iteration.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a int
    for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
        a=i+1 // GOOD: a isn't allocated new memory on every iteration
        fmt.Printf("i-val: %d, i-addr: %p, a-val: %d, a-addr: %p\n", i, &i, a, &a)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
% go build -gcflags="-m" ./shortdecl.go
# command-line-arguments
./shortdecl.go:16:19: inlining call to fmt.Printf
./shortdecl.go:11:9: moved to heap: a
./shortdecl.go:12:9: moved to heap: i
./shortdecl.go:16:19: ... argument does not escape
./shortdecl.go:16:70: i escapes to heap
./shortdecl.go:16:77: a escapes to heap

% ./shortdecl
i-val: 0, i-addr: 0x1400000e140, a-val: 1, a-addr: 0x1400000e138
i-val: 1, i-addr: 0x1400000e140, a-val: 2, a-addr: 0x1400000e138
i-val: 2, i-addr: 0x1400000e140, a-val: 3, a-addr: 0x1400000e138
i-val: 3, i-addr: 0x1400000e140, a-val: 4, a-addr: 0x1400000e138
i-val: 4, i-addr: 0x1400000e140, a-val: 5, a-addr: 0x1400000e138
i-val: 5, i-addr: 0x1400000e140, a-val: 6, a-addr: 0x1400000e138
i-val: 6, i-addr: 0x1400000e140, a-val: 7, a-addr: 0x1400000e138
i-val: 7, i-addr: 0x1400000e140, a-val: 8, a-addr: 0x1400000e138
i-val: 8, i-addr: 0x1400000e140, a-val: 9, a-addr: 0x1400000e138
i-val: 9, i-addr: 0x1400000e140, a-val: 10, a-addr: 0x1400000e138
```

Comment: These are implementation details that vary from compiler to compiler and version to version. Your variables escape because you pass it to fmt.Printf. You are (vastly) overestimating the performance impact of this heap allocation so 3, 4 and 5 are basically based on false assumptions (well, 5 only party because it's _you_ who passed a in an empty interface to fmt.Printf).

Comment: @Volker Why passing a or i to fmt.Printf need heap allocation? That doesn’t make sense! fmt.Printf is on the child call stack frame relative to where a and i are declared.

Comment: Go is open source. You are free to provide a patch that doesn't move a and i to the heap :-)  I'm not the expert here you might find question about why passing variables through `any` result in the escaping in the current compiler. Escape analysis is complicated and not all optimizations are worth their cost. In any case asking for "why?" is mostly OT as there typically are no good answers.

Answer (score 2):

> A quick test reveals that go allocates new memory in every iteration when one uses short variable declaration.

This is wrong. It's not the "short variable declaration" that causes a heap allocation - it's the variable usage. A contrived example:

```golang
sum := 0
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    a := i+1
    sum += a
}
// do something with sum...
```

As expected, the "short variable declaration" `a := i+1` does not cause a heap allocation in itself at all; after all it's equivalent to `var a int = i+1`, and why should that cause a heap allocation?

Note that Go's "address of" operator is *not* like C's "address of": It will by default cause a heap allocation, since Go imposes no restrictions on the lifetime of a pointer; garbage collection takes care of this for you. The following creates an array of 10 valid pointers, whereas in C you'd have to explicitly `malloc` each int:

```golang
ptrs := make([]*int, 10)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    a := i+1
    ptrs[i] = &a
}
// do something with ptrs...
```

In particular, `&a` need not directly take the address of a value on a stack as in C; in fact it could only do this if the Go compiler could somehow prove that the lifetime of a pointer does not extend beyond the lifetime of the value on the stack (which would be a "dangling pointer"). You don't get these "dangling pointers" in Go because Go simply does heap allocations.

Probably due to the use of reflection (`Println` for example takes `...any`, so the Go compiler will probably "tag" the `int` here before passing it), variables seem to always escape to the heap if `fmt.Print*` is involved. For example, `a` still escapes to the heap in the following scenario, despite the lack of an explicit "address of":

```golang
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    a := i+1
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

To answer your questions:

1. Most probably because of its usage (being passed to `Printf`, addressof).
2. Same as `i`.
3. This is wrong. Go is garbage-collected, the `int`s will be freed after `Printf` is done with them; at some point Go will thus stop requesting new pages.
4. Yes, when you actually want a new variable, e.g. as upvalue of a closure. This is [being fixed in Go 1.22](https://go.dev/blog/loopvar-preview).
5. I'm not on the team, but I would hazard a guess that adding support for such optimizations would make the compiler significantly more complex. Go simply hasn't taken the "full monomorphization" route; reflection and generics come at a runtime cost. I imagine compiler speed may also be of concern.

Comment: If calling ``fmt.Printf*`` on a variable causes such side effects, is there a side-effect-free way of printing the value of a variable?

Comment: @codepoet why would you? The heap allocation of the integer will most probably be negligible in comparison to all the logic of the formatting function (which may include heap allocations for the string buffer it's writing to) and the I/O. Do you have a profile where the heap allocation is actually an issue? I can't think of an easy way to output a string without a heap allocation. Something like `os.Stdout.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(i))` would still be doing a heap allocation (for the string). You can of course write a heap-alloc-free number stringify yourself, but it probably isn't worth it.

Comment: I meant side effect on surrounding logic that is being observed, in this case variables like ``a`` and ``i``. It is ok if a log/print technique does heap allocation for it's own logic. But it is not ok if calling a print/log function moves the variable under observation from stack to heap, as that changes the logic being observed. IMO that's a significant side effect, and makes it difficult to reason about program logic under observation. Observing program logic should not change it.

Comment: @codepoet but the observed program logic does not change? As far as Go is concerned, whether a variable lives on the stack or the heap is a (performance-relevant) implementation detail, and not really "observable" program behavior. When using a language like Go, you give up on doing fine-grained manual memory management yourself.

Comment: It's not just about stack and heap. In this example, there is an unnecessary new allocation on every iteration! The book on go calls us to be mindful of memory allocation. Not all observability is about fine-grain memory management or trying to squeeze last bit of performance. Observability (without side effects on observed logic) helps one understand the tool they are working with to make better decisions.

Comment: @codepoet you still haven't demonstrated that this "unnecessary" allocation is in any way a performance concern. Inserting `print`s is a bad way to observe program performance; use a proper profiler.

Comment: You really think a tight loop's performance won't be affected by allocations every cycle? There is nothing to prove or disprove, don't distract the question with statements. Anyway, I am asking for a way to log/output/observe program state without affecting the behavior of logic being observed. It can be for as simple a task as understanding some piece of logic, not just for observing performance.

Comment: @codepoet for other funcs that take `interface{}`, it may be an issue. For `print` and variants in particular, it likely is not. `print` is "fine" for observing logic, though you may want to use something like a debugger, or a profiler if you want to observe performance in particular. Where something is allocated is *not* Go program logic however.